# Is there a shorter expression for 'are not commonly discussed as much as'?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english

I am currently doing some writing, and constantly try to create smooth transition and ease of readability and linkage between sentences. This sentence feels like it kind of halts the reader a bit.

> Albeit although assemblers are not commonly discussed as much as the
> two language processors, they are, however, equally important in the
> pipeline.

Replace 'are not commonly discussed as much as' with something that virtually means the exact same but, might be a single word.

Comment: 'Albeit although' - pick one. Drop 'however', & suddenly the whole sentence loses the limp. The part you're asking about is not the problem.

Comment: The previous version of this question seemed like open-ended proofreading, which is off topic. However, asking for a word/phrase is squarely on topic. For best results, [review the tag wiki](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests).

Comment: Simplify to "Assemblers are not discussed as much as the two language processors, but are equally important in the pipeline."

Comment: Though the question is arguably on-topic, the answers being offered are, while good writing advice ... writing advice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth does rephrasing count as a phrase-request?

Comment: Replacing a perfectly valid word / longer expression is both asking for style advice and usually open-ended, @
stevesliva
.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase **receive less attention than** would work here and save you a few words. Ultimately, though, this is all a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the verbiage by using a comparative form. If you change "not commonly" to "less frequently", then you can reduce "as much as" to "than":

> Although assemblers are less frequently discussed than the two language processors, they are equally important in the pipeline.

Note that I got rid of the conjunction "albeit" (which was not appropriate in that position) and "however" (which was redundant due to the presence of "although"). (Tetsujin first suggested that, in a comment above.)

Comment: *are discussed less than* gets you all the way to as short as using synonyms like *are less notable than* or *noteworthy* etc.

Comment: @stevesliva I don't understand your comment entirely, but I think that you're suggesting "less noteable" or "less noteworthy" instead of my "less frequently discussed". Yes, that would reduce the length by one word, but it would also change the meaning a bit more than my version does.

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing "Dogs are not commonly discussed as much as cats" to "People discuss cats more than dogs."  6 words, not 9; 8 syllables, not 12; 29 letters, not 39.

Brevity aside, three issues present.  The revision is in the active voice, whereas the original is not.  Generally, the active is preferred to the passive voice.

Second, both expressions might suffer from the critiques of pettifogging grammar dweebs who'd insist on "Dogs are not as commonly discussed as cats are" and "People discuss cats more than they do dogs." I'd concede the point but argue its usefulness.

Finally, the revision subtly alters the sentence's meaning in that it changes emphases.  The original focuses on dogs receiving less attention than cats, hinting that dogs are losing out somehow.  The revision is feline focused: cats are more interesting, more worthy than dogs.  A nuanced difference, I admit, but not an insignificant one.

All good editing is reductive.  The best editing clarifies as well.

Answer (score 1):

An idiom you might use is **get short shrift**, although there's probably a large chunk of your audience who will be back here asking what it means. One of its meanings is "get little attention".

> Assemblers get short shrift but they're no less important in the pipeline than the two language processors.

Comment: Based on what I imagine the context to be, this sounds a bit too informal to me.

Comment: @Casey: "pipeline" seems a rather informal metaphor to me, so I don't think there is a register clash, but I take your point. I  had upvoted **receive less attention** as neutral.